# Enable Thread Safety for Php Version 5.6.2

Tags: php, linux, multithreading

I have the below php version installed in my linux server.

[image]

Now I want to run the below program -

```
<?php
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {

public function __construct($arg) {
    $this->arg = $arg;
}

public function run() {
    if ($this->arg) {
        $sleep = mt_rand(1, 10);
        printf('%s: %s  -start -sleeps %d' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg, $sleep);
        sleep($sleep);
        printf('%s: %s  -finish' . "\n", date("g:i:sa"), $this->arg);
    }
}
}

// Create a array
$stack = array();

//Iniciate Miltiple Thread
foreach ( range("A", "D") as $i ) {
$stack[] = new AsyncOperation($i);
}

// Start The Threads
foreach ( $stack as $t ) {
$t->start();
}
?>
```

I need to enable Thread safety for my php installation. Can somebody inform me how can I do so ?

Comment: Found this Googling for the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, There is no easy and straight forward way to do so. The best option is to re-install PHP from a Thread Safety Installer.

Comment: Yes, that's a given :-) I meant: did you find a TS package somewhere?

Comment: Please check it here - http://windows.php.net/download/

Comment: We were talking about Ubuntu, weren't we? :-/

Comment: You may be right. But I did the installation in one of my windows server and there I have used that package.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, [I asked the package maintainer](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/41#issuecomment-71018346):

> If you want to use threaded version of PHP, you are on your own. While
>   it might work just fine in a specific environment, it's not
>   thread-safe in all possible scenarios (including loading external
>   modules) and thus it's not wise to provide "thread-safe" packages for
>   general use.

So, no way out :-/